# How to build this layout using GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

I would like to build a layout as shown below using `GridView` though I am aware that it can be done using `GridLayout` & `ScrollView` but I need to use adapter because I do kind of lazy loading and scalling for images.

[image]

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is the **StaggeredGridView**:

> The StaggeredGridView allows the user to create a GridView with uneven rows similar to how Pinterest looks. Includes own OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener, selector, and fixed position restore

http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/

Comment: I have seen `StaggeredGridView` before but actually could not find a way to customize it as seen in the image, do you have any hint how to do so?

Comment: With this library I can scroll down but not up.I have filled an issue in the repo.
Anyone got it to work it properly. The demo also has the same problem.

Comment: this is happening with me too as soon as I click any item

Comment: You can check out the library I made based on the existing ACL implementation. https://github.com/Utopia-Developers/StaggeredGridView